# VBA Code for Div Class

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching for an answer for days. Please help.

```
<div class="FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice">$3.8391</div>
```

I just need to pull the "$3.8391" from this string within the website and have it populate into a cell in Excel.

Here's what I have so far, all of which works exactly how I need it to. I have gotten the web page to open, log in and search for a location, however, I can't seem to get this one simple number!!

(I obviously changed the username/password in the code to protect my information)

```
Sub login()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    IE.AddressBar = 0
    IE.StatusBar = 0
    IE.Toolbar = 0
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.avfuel.com/login"
    Do Until Not IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Set doc = IE.document
    Do While doc.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
    doc.getElementsByName("dnn$ctr2046$Login$Login_AvfuelAuth$txtUserName")(0).Value = "XXXX"
    doc.getElementsByName("dnn$ctr2046$Login$Login_AvfuelAuth$txtPassword")(0).Value = "XXXXX"
    doc.getElementById("dnn_ctr2046_Login_Login_AvfuelAuth_cmdLogin").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    doc.getElementsByName("dnn$ctr618$Loader$ctl00$txtAirportSearchInput")(0).Value = "bfl"
    doc.getElementById("dnn_ctr618_Loader_ctl00_hlSearchPageAirport").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Cells(1,1) = doc.getElementsByClassName("FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice")(0).innerText
```

Comment: This is perfect! Now, instead of it populating a message box, how do I get it to input it into cell within table in Excel?

Comment: Remvove `Msgbox` and replace with `Cells(1,1)=`

Comment: I tried that and I am getting "Compile Error: Expected: End of statement"
I'm seriously new, can you tell, haha!

Comment: Okay another question.

Comment: Sure, Please post & share link. Will pickup.

Comment: Okay another question.

I have an instance where there are several numbers that all have the same Id and its only pulling one. 

    <div class="FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice">$3.9362</div>
    <div class="FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice">$3.9862</div>
    <div class="FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice">$4.1362</div>

Comment: Use `doc.getElementsByClassName("FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice")(0).nextSibling.Value`

Comment: That populated the cell with "[object HTMLDivElement]" instead of the values.

Comment: "Runtime Error: '438': Object doesnt support this property or method"  
Sorry for all the questions, I'm teaching myself VBA for a project at work.

Comment: No worries   try `doc.getElementsByClassName("FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice")(0).nextSibling.innerText` or `doc.getElementsByClassName("FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice").nextSibling.innerText`

Comment: So its not doing exactly what I want it to do still but I am not sure how to explain what its doing without a photo. Do you have an email or messaging system we can chat on instead?

Comment: Yes, join here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176280/aspiring-stars

Comment: I emailed you :)

Comment: Ok.will check and reply asap

Answer (score 0):

Or use CSS selector

e.g.

```
[A1] = doc.querySelector(".FBOSearchResultsItemPricingTablePrice").innerText
```

The "." is for class.